# Is there a readable built-in generalization of the `zip` method with automatic "unpacking" of tuples?

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, iteration, built-in, code-readability

Given two lists `a=[(1,11), (2,22), (3,33)]` and `b=[111, 222, 333]` I would like to know if there is a syntactically easy-to-read solution to iterate over triples of values as follows:

```
for x,y,z in WANTED(a, b):
    print(x, y, z)

# should iterate over (1,11,111), (2,22,222), (3,33,333)
```

*I do know* that this can be done like

```
for _item, z in zip(a, b):
    x, y = _item
    print(x, y, z)
```

and I also *do know* how to pack this into my own custom iterator, but I'd like to know if this is possible using low level built-in solutions (maybe `itertools`) to achieve this with syntactically easy-to-read code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do:

```py
a = [(1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33)]
b = [111, 222, 333]

for (x, y), z in zip(a, b):  # <-- note the (x, y)
    print(x, y, z)
```

This prints:

```
1 11 111
2 22 222
3 33 333
```

Comment: Thanks, turned out I was rather missing some basic knownledge on syntax than a "generalization" of some method :) I use this very often now, e.g. it is even more helpful when using `enumerate` with lists of tuples.